# CouchBase Replication Load Balancing - How to reduce the frequency of client replication attempts on failure

Tags: android, couchdb, replication, couchbase

I'm new to Couch, and have inherited a medium-sized project that uses CouchBase Mobile (Developer Preview V2.0) on about 70 client Android phones (all HTC Desire S), which then sync with a master CouchDB server.

Unfortunately, the person who built the system is no longer here, so I'm looking for some help from the community.

***My Observations:***

- The client phones seem to be in an almost constant state of invoking replication, then failing, then re-invoking replication, failing, etc. In addition to failing to pull down new data from the server, it also eats up an inordinate amount of battery power.
- The server is observably overburdened. Erlang and Couch are soaking up a lot of CPU and Memory.
- When the server is less burdened, replication seems to work fine. After re-starting the CouchDB service, for example, replication works fine for a little while.

***My Assumptions:***

- To me, this smells like a load balancing problem. As the server becomes busy, replication fails for more and more clients, which then just request replication more often, making the problem worse.

***How I've Tried To Fix It:***

- In the CouchBase "default.ini" file on the clients, I have edited the following in an attempt to limiting how often the clients invoke replication.

  - max_replication_retry_count = 1
  - http_connections            = 5
  - connection_timeout          = 60000

In spite of this, I can still see CouchBase ploughing away in LogCat, incessantly trying and failing to replicate.

Can anyone suggest how I might begin debugging this, so as to isolate the problem more effectively? Point me in the right direction?... Many thanks.

---

***Here's the replication error from LogCat***
09-28 12:48:48.593: I/CouchDB(4468): [info] [<0.8140.0>] Replication `"0284a8a927077abfd2b86a2616e07fed"` is using:
09-28 12:48:48.593: I/CouchDB(4468):    4 worker processes
09-28 12:48:48.593: I/CouchDB(4468):    a worker batch size of 500
09-28 12:48:48.593: I/CouchDB(4468):    5 HTTP connections
09-28 12:48:48.593: I/CouchDB(4468):    a connection timeout of 60000 milliseconds
09-28 12:48:48.593: I/CouchDB(4468):    socket options are: [{keepalive,true},{nodelay,false}]
09-28 12:48:48.593: I/CouchDB(4468):    source start sequence 4971
09-28 12:48:49.824: I/CouchDB(4468): [info] [<0.8140.0>] Document `funf_client_to_server_49fd7812-409d-47df-a1cd-888db15a24ae` triggered replication `0284a8a927077abfd2b86a2616e07fed`
09-28 12:48:49.834: I/CouchDB(4468): [info] [<0.8139.0>] starting new replication `0284a8a927077abfd2b86a2616e07fed` at <0.8140.0> (`funf` -> `https://*****@monarca.dk:5984/monarca_funf/`)
09-28 12:48:51.225: E/CouchDB(4468): [error] [<0.8140.0>] ChangesReader process died with reason: {file_corruption,
09-28 12:48:51.225: E/CouchDB(4468):                                                               <<"file corruption">>}
09-28 12:48:51.225: E/CouchDB(4468): [error] [<0.8140.0>] Replication `0284a8a927077abfd2b86a2616e07fed` (`funf` -> `https://*****@monarca.dk:5984/monarca_funf/`) failed: changes_reader_died
09-28 12:48:51.245: I/CouchDB(4468): [info] [<0.8149.0>] Retrying POST request to https://*****@monarca.dk:5984/monarca_funf/_revs_diff in 0.25 seconds due to error closing_on_request
09-28 12:48:51.245: I/CouchDB(4468): [info] [<0.8148.0>] Retrying POST request to https://*****@monarca.dk:5984/monarca_funf/_revs_diff in 0.25 seconds due to error closing_on_request
09-28 12:48:51.476: E/CouchDB(4468): [error] [<0.298.0>] Error in replication `0284a8a927077abfd2b86a2616e07fed` (triggered by document `funf_client_to_server_49fd7812-409d-47df-a1cd-888db15a24ae`): changes_reader_died

---

***Here's the replication doc in question.***
{"_id":"funf_client_to_server_49fd7812-409d-47df-a1cd-888db15a24ae","_rev":"825-082674db3441880a23d6b6aa51be7e3e","target":"https://*****@monarca.dk:5984/monarca_funf","continuous":false,"source":"funf","filter":"monarcaandroid/deletefilter","_replication_id":"3dfdfca7dfd47d9352c9048497660e4c","_replication_state":"error","_replication_state_time":"2012-09-28T12:51:25+02:00"}

---

***And here's the "deletefilter" referenced by the replication doc.***

```
"function(doc) {\n  return !doc._deleted;\n}"
```

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is couchbase mobile on android, I think that is based on about couchdb 1.1 or an early couchdb 1.2. THis might be before the the settings you tried (max_replication_retry_count, http_connections, and connection_timeout) landed in couchdb 1.2 release version. That is only a guess. You may want to 1) upgrade your couchdb/couchbase version (and please let us all know if you find a later build), or 2) Just have a timer task to do a single replication in the background.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ryan. The phones are running Mobile CouchBase Developer Preview V2.0. As far as I know, there isn't anything newer out there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Better use the `_replicator` database for replication. It will do the replication re-attempts for you for free. The delay before making a re-attempt for replication increases exponentially.

Information available from [here](https://gist.github.com/832610)

Comment: My previous comment was mistaken. The code IS using the '_replicator' database, not a timer. (Sorry, I'm still learning the ins and outs of this app...) I also noticed that the documentation mentions that replication re-attempts occur exponentially less often, but I'm not seeing that behavior. Not sure why...

Comment: I'm using the `_replicator` database and I see an exponential increase in the delay for re-attempts. You might be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The error log says 'file corruption'; may be that hints at some couch db corruption. You may want to look at your _replicator db for any corruption.